# Input from 2 different forms in Javascript Validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am using the following design in order to validate the age input (must be greater than 18):

The form is the following:

```
<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <div class="input-group date">
                <form:input path="legal_resp.birth_date" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder ="ηη/µµ/εεεε" data-validbirthdate="true"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon btn">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div> 
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            <form:errors path="legal_resp.birth_date" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
        </div>
```

The options that I pass as argument to the .validator are the following:

```
var options={
      custom: {

            validbirthdate: function (input) {
                var str= input.val();
                if(str == '')
                    return true;
                var parts = str.split('/');

                if (parts.length < 3)
                    return false;
                else {
                    var day = parseInt(parts[0]);
                    var month = parseInt(parts[1]);
                    var year = parseInt(parts[2]);
                    if (isNaN(day) || isNaN(month) || isNaN(year)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (day < 1 || year < 1)
                        return false;
                    if(month>12||month<1)
                        return false;
                    if ((month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && day > 31)
                        return false;
                    if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 ) && day > 30)
                        return false;
                    if (month == 2) {
                        if (((year % 4) == 0 && (year % 100) != 0) || ((year % 400) == 0 && (year % 100) == 0)) {
                            if (day > 29)
                                return false;
                        } else {
                            if (day > 28)
                                return false;
                        }      
                    }

                    var d = new Date(year, month-1, day);

                    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - d.getTime();
                    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
                    var age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);

                    if(age<18)
                        return false;
                    return true;   

                   }
                }
```

I have the following question:

I want to exted the function in order to take input from 2 different forms (2 age inputs) and compare them. I understand that I need another argument for my function. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Date parsing is a solved problem. Instead of rolling your own date parser, please use one of the well-tested libraries available.

Comment: Still, the main issue is the multiple arguments input, not the validator itself!

Comment: Where are you using this validation object? If it's in a plugin you most likely will have to do the check yourself inside code shown or only use one form

Comment: No it's not a plugin